# Installed add ons are not visible as separate tabs in sidebar

Tags: interface, add-on, customization

I have a problem with addons in all 2.8x blender versions (in 2.79 version it works propertly). All of addons are NOT visible in the right sidebar, as separate tabs. There are only visible in option "Tools"->Workspace (also right sidebar). You can select them, but it doesn't change anything because there is no possibility to use it (e.x TextFX Addon). Or maybe I don't know how to use it?... I tried to find any tutorial, but in every tutorial there is this same situation - everybody (after installing addons and activated it) have them visible in the right sidebar as separate tab. What do I do wrong? Is it preferences case? Can you help?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Both *Rigify* and *LoopTools* tabs only show up in Edit mode. Are you in Edit mode?

Comment: Hello :) You're right. They're visible in edit mode! Thanks :) But I still can't fix Text FX Addon problem. :( I can't find it anywhere. BTW, Is there possibility to make all those addons visible as separate tabs? It's a little strange, that all users have it (especially in older 2.8x versions), and in my case it's available in this way... Espaecially, if I want to use another addons in the future...